# Kann man Präteritum und Perfekt in einem Satz mischen, der sich auf die Vergangenheit bezieht?

Tags: grammaticality, tense, perfect-tense, past, preterite

Ich wollte fragen, was es denn für Beispiele gibt, in denen ich Präteritum und Perfekt im gleichen Satz verwenden kann. Ist z. B.

> Ich habe mich selbst überrascht, als ich gestern siegte

grammatikalisch korrekt? Präteritum und Perfekt werden darin gebraucht. Soll man eher

> Ich überraschte mich, als ich gestern siegte

sagen?

Ich habe das Gefühl, dass bei Verwendung nur einer der beiden Zeiten in einem Satzgefüge wenig Raum für kreative Beschreibung bleibt.

Comment: Mir scheint nur der erste Satz richtig, aber ich kann es leider nicht erklären.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In der Verwendung *als reine Vergangenheitstempora* (das Perfekt hat nämlich noch andere Aspekte!) sind Präteritum und Perfekt semantisch eigentlich komplett austauschbar; somit würde ich Ardoris widersprechen, und die von die vorgeschlagene Kombination als durchaus grammatisch bezeichnen.  Deutsch hat hierfür auch keine Consecutio-Temporum-Regel oder ähnliches, die eine bestimmte Wahl von beiden abhängig vom Kontext festlegen würde.

Allerdings hängt die Wahl, welches Tempus tatsächlich verwendet wird, zum Großteil von verschiedenen regionalen und stilistischen, also pragmatischen Faktoren ab, was dein Beispiel in vielen Kontexten problematisch macht:

- In der formalen und Schriftsprache wird beinahe ausschließlich das Präteritum verwendet, ohne regionale Variation (Ausnahmen sind wörtliche Reden, literarische Stilmittel, und gewisse Tendenzen wie zB. *hast gebadet* statt *badetest* wegen der "Umständlichkeit" der Formulierung).  Das Perfekt im Beispielsatz ist somit grundsätzlich inakzeptabel.
- In der Umgangssprache gibt es ein Nord-Süd-Gefälle von ausschließlichem Präteritumgebrauch zu ausschließlichem Perfektgebrauch.  An den "Polen" davon (Norddeutschland/Österreich) wären also jeweils für sich genommen die Kombination inakzeptabel, allein wegen der Verwendung der "falschen" Zeit.

In "mittleren" Regionen, oder "gemischten" auch schriftlichen Kontexten (Foren, Chat), ist umgangssprachlich die Vermischung ziemlich akzeptabel, würde ich sagen, weil eindeutig verständlich -- wenn sie auch von kaum jemandem als "sprachlich gut" bewertet würde.

Als Konklusion: sollte man vermeiden.  Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, wie der "kreative Freiraum" dadurch eingeschränkt wird (mit den genannten Ausnahmen), außer es geht um Metrik-Füllungen in gebundener Sprache.

Comment: Gute Punkte, an die ich nicht gedacht hatte (ich bin von "streng" literarischen Texten ausgegangen). +1 von mir.

Comment: Ich hoffe nur, dass niemand die wichtige Einschränkung in der Klammer gleich im ersten Satz überliest.

Comment: Mit Kursiv und Rufzeichen ist denke ich das Nötige getan. Ich will ja niemanden anschreien :)

Comment: Vielen vielen Dank fuer deine ausführliche Antwort! Eine Frage, du sagst mein Beispiel ist grammatisch, später aber nennst du es inakzeptabel. Ich bin sehr froh ueber deine Antwort, jetzt jedoch, durch diesen Wiederspruch, verwirrt. Koenntest du mir das nochmal erklären. Liege ich also richtig das grammatisch meine Beispiele richtig sind, da dein erster Stichpunkte jedoch sagt, dass in formaler Schriftsprache ausschließlich Präteritum verwendet wird, das perfekt fehl am Platz ist und ich beim Präteritum bleiben sollte, das perfekt jedoch nicht als falsch gesehen werden darf? Vielen Dank dir

Comment: Vielen vielen Dank fuer deine ausführliche Antwort!

Comment: Eine Frage noch zusätzlich : Du sagst "stilistischen, also pragmatischen Faktoren ab" da ich grad noch kommasetzung in deutscher Sprache lerne, würde ich gern wissen, ob zwischen, also pragmatischen, und Faktoren ab ein Komma kommt, da "also pragmatischen" fuer mich, wie eine zusätzliche Erläuterung klingt, ein kleiner erklärende Einschub. Mich interessiert das echt brennend. Hoffe du kannst mir diese Frage noch beantworten und danke sehr fuer deine Zeit!

Comment: Ad "Grammatisch" und "akzeptabel": die Begriffe haben [in der Linguistik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akzeptabilit%C3%A4t) bestimmte, woneinander abgegrenzte Bedeutungen, die einander nicht ganz überlappen, siehe dort. Der gemischte Satz ist syntaktisch richtig, würde aber von den meisten Sprechern in den genannten Kontexten aufgrund pragmatischer Einschränkunken nie so geäußert, und eben als "schlechtes Deutsch" gewertet.

Comment: Ad Komma: gute Frage. Ich habe mir mit Kommasetzung immer schon leicht getan, aber mache sie immer nur nach Gefühl -- primär dort, wo eine Pause kommt, wie in dieser Phrase. Dein Argument ist richtig und ein zweites Komma, weil es sich um einen Einschub handelt, wäre auf keinen Fall falsch; zu meiner Variante kann ich nur sagen, dass sie mir idiomatischer Vorkommt. Ich fürchte, du musst eine gesonderte Frage dazu stellen.

Comment: Beim zweiten Nachdenken würde ich argumentieren, dass _regionalen und stilistischen, also pragmatischen_ aus zwei koordinierten Adjektivphrasen besteht, also gemeinsam _Faktoren_ modifiziert und kein Einschub ist. Aber das ist rein an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Answer (score 1):

Dein erstes Beispiel vermischt die Tempusformen. Sowohl Perfekt als auch Präteritum (Imperfekt) deuten auf eine Aktion in der Vergangenheit hin. Der Unterschied der beiden liegt darin, dass das Präteritum die Haupterzählzeit sein kann. Viele Romane und andere literarische Texte sind darin verfasst.
Beispiel:

> *Ich ging nach der Arbeit noch in die Bar. Dort traf ich meine Freunde auf ein Bier.*

Hat eine Aktion vor der Erzählzeit stattgefunden und ist abgeschlossen, dann muss das Plusquamperfekt verwendet werden (beispielsweise durch temporale Konjunktion **nachdem** verdeutlicht).
Beispiel:

> *Nachdem mich mein Chef gefeuert hatte, lief ich in die Bar. Denn leider hatte ich mein Bahnticket verloren.*

Perfekt wird genutzt, um eine Handlung zu schildern, die in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat. Dabei ist die Haupterzählzeit allerdings Präsens (Gegenwart).
Beispiel:

> *Die Freunde haben auf mich gewartet. Sehr gut, jetzt können wir loslegen.*

Die Vermischung von Präteritum und Perfekt ist nie grammatikalisch korrekt (oder zumindest kann ich mir gerade kein sinnvolles Beispiel damit vorstellen). Daher ist in deinem Beispiel die zweite Variante besser (doch auch hier kann das Plusquamperfekt genutzt werden):

> *Ich überraschte mich, als ich gestern siegte.*
> *Ich überraschte mich, als ich gestern gesiegt hatte.*

Comment: Ich danke danke danke danke dir fuer so eine extrem deutliche Antwort!

Comment: Das ist extrem freundlich, vielen vielen Dank dir!

Comment: Eine klare Antwort, aber so vielleicht für literarische Erzähltexte zutreffend. In der Alltagssprache ist die Vermischung von Perfekt und Präteritum vollkommen üblich. Daher -1 von mir.

Comment: In der Alltagssprache (mündlich!) wird im Süden vor allem das Perfekt verwendet, im Norden andersherum.
Da in dem Beispiel Imperfekt verwendet wurde, bin ich von literarischen Texten ausgegangen. Aber ich stimme dir diesbezüglich zu.